# Rspec capybara webkit cant find button tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I have the following test

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Menu", :type => :feature do

 let!(:articles) { create_list(:article, 10) }
 let!(:quotes) { create_list(:quote, 2) }

 before { visit "/" }

 scenario "should not have Javascript errors" do
   Capybara.current_driver = :webkit

   page.find("#menu-button").click

   expect(page).not_to have_errors
 end

end
```

and it fails with the message

*Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#menu-button"*

I also tried

```
click_on "Open Menu"

click_button "Open Menu"

click_link "Open Menu"

page.find_button(id: 'menu-button').click

find("#menu-button").click
```

I am trying to test the off canvas feature that foundation 6 has.

application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Stargazers.news" %></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper">

  <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
    <button class="close-button" arial-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close></button>

    <div id="search">
      <%= form_tag({controller: "/pages", action:"search"}, method: "get") do %>
        <%= label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:search) %>
        <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
      <% end %>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <button id="menu-button" type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvas">Open Menu</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the index.html.erb file

```
<div id="quote">
  <%= @quote.body %>
</div>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <article>
    <header> <%= article.title%> </header>
    <div class="content-summary"> <%= article.body %> </div>
  </article>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
```

rails_helper.rb file

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'simple_bdd/rspec'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.include RSpecHtmlMatchers

  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:suite) do 
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start 
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end 

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'rspec-html-matchers'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'simple_bdd'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "better_errors"
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

my qt version is 5.5.1
and I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Capybara doesn't find non-visible elements, and 99% of the time it can't interact with a non-visible element.  This is because it's designed to emulate a users behavior and a user can't interact with something they can't see on the page.

UPDATE: now that you've included the whole test the issue is clearer. You're not setting the test to use :webkit until after the visit '/' has occurred. This means the :racktest driver visits the page but then you swap to the :webkit driver which hasn't actually loaded any page, so there is nothing there. Rather than manually setting current_driver in the test you should just be tagging the test with `js: true` (or `driver: :webkit`) metadata

```
scenario "should not have Javascript errors", js: true do
  ...
end
```

That will then set the current driver to the value of Capybara.javascript_driver (which you've set to :webkit) before the visit occurs.

Additionally your database_cleaner setup is lacking a bit - it should be the suggested setup - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example -  The swap from after to append_after is important for test stability and the checks for driver type will help speed up your tests.

Finally, there is no need to specify `:type => :feature` if you're already using `RSpec.feature`

Comment: hello @ThomasWalpole, the `off-canvas-content` is visible element, I also tried `page.driver.console_messages` and `page.driver.error_messages` and I didn't get any errors. But, when I commented the `page.find("#menu-button").click` and got the `expected #<Capybara::Session:0x0055e13c4e07a0> to respond to 'has_errors?'` message. I feel confused with this message because I think it means that webkit it's not installed.

Comment: @stupidone Having the full test info makes it much clearer -- I've updated my answer.

Comment: You are right, I was facing the same issue but after adding js: true it's working well now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `visible: false` to your `find` call, like this:

```
page.find("#menu-button", visible: false).click
```